# Number of active netlists exceeds limit

Tags: limit, fpga, vivado, netlist

Lately, I have been stuck with the same error from Vivado when I try to Synthesize my design:

> [Common 17-70] Application Exception: Number of active netlists exceeds limit (255)

Does anybody know what this "limit" means? Is it a limitation of the software, or it refers to the capacity of the FPGA? Is there some way to avoid it, or do I have to change all my design in order to have fewer netlists?

Comment: Is this a webpack license or a payed license?

Comment: I'm using the HL Design edition, which is payed license.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Restarting the vivado tool helped in my case.